# Traducción de "brew" al español

Tags: traducción, verbos, vocabulario-técnico, comida

¿Existe una palabra en español para definir "Brew"?

En inglés normalmente "brew" es solamente una parte del proceso al hablar de la elaboración de alguna bebida que requiere calentar, reposar y mezclar. Es por eso que se usa tanto como para té, café y cerveza. Sin embargo no se utiliza para vino u otros fermentos que no requieren la parte de "hervir".

Si traducimos "Brew" directamente al español los "traductores" nos arrojarán simplemente "Preparar cerveza".

¿Existe una palabra en español que englobe este proceso y pueda ser utilizado para sus contrapartes en inglés que no sea "preparar"?

Comment: Poner a fermentar, poner a reposar, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Elaborar cerveza: brew beer.

El tema se discute en el interesante artículo [*El arte de elaborar cerveza*](https://www.cervezalasagra.es/el-arte-de-elaborar-cerveza/) (de una sociedad de cerveza artesanal, La Sagra,) del cual cito una parte pertinente:

> [...] "Acepción 1. Transformar una cosa u obtener un producto por medio de un trabajo adecuado. Acepción 2. Idea o inventar algo complejo.
>
> Así define el diccionario de la Real Academia Española de la Lengua ‘elaborar’, una palabra que en el imaginario popular transmite sensación de calma, de trabajo hecho sin prisas. **Elaborar no es lo mismo que Hacer, por mucho que el resultado final pueda parecerlo**.
>
> En el mundo de la cerveza, no es lo mismo ‘elaborar’ que ‘producir’ o ‘fabricar’. La cerveza artesana se elabora. Es un trabajo casi de orfebre, pero en el que es necesario apostar por la innovación para adecuarse a los tiempos que vivimos." [...]

El verbo *elaborar* también sirve para la preparación de café. Véase por ejemplo [*Consejos para elaborar un café Espresso*](https://cafeslabrasilena.es/blog/consejos-para-elaborar-un-cafe-espresso/).

Comment: Si se trata de "witch's brew" podría decir pócima.

Comment: Sería otra acepción. A witch brews a potion. elaborar también.